# Count and operations in Neo4j cypher

Tags: count, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying one query, like this:

```
MATCH (g:GNE)-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WHERE g.sym = 'ST1' AND count(c) >=4  
RETURN h.sym, count(c) AS score, collect(c.clustInfo), h.chr ORDER BY score DESC
```

but the expression 'count(c) >= 4' doesn't work...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly use aggregates in a WHERE clause like that, you need to use [WITH](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html) to create a new variable for testing in subsequent conditions. You query becomes something like:

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WITH h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info
ORDER BY score DESC
WHERE score >= 4
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

Comment: Many thanks! I would like ADD the follow pattern in this sentence: other nodes that are related with the nodes CLUSTER and are common in all cluster. Some thing like this: `(c:CLUSTER)-[:has]-(v:ORTH)` where v.Term are equal in all CLUSTER. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @quelopes that needs to be asked as a new question. Good luck!